# Can I replace this Asus laptop's motherboard with a different but very similar one?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, hardware-failure

The motherboard of my Asus N550JK DS71T laptop broke. The model of the motherboard reads *60NB04L0-MB1030(216)*.

Will replacing it with a model *60NB04L0-**MB1021**(216)* work?

Comment: If it will physically fit and external ports line up with the case openings,then it should be good, only potential problem is if the video chip will not work with your lcd for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You should really not replace your mainboard by a mainboard with another model number if you want to use the parts on it you used so far. I mean you can have luck and everything works fine but maybe you have not - and then you invested a lot of money for nothing.

As I can see the part number does not differ in something like the revision number but in one of the essential parts. So it is not even clear whether the new mainboard fits into your notebooks case.

I the case your mainboard has a hardware failure and you can't claim warranty anymore, then it is really more advisable to buy a complete new notebook. Belive me: I made experiences with replacing broken parts. The lifetime of the parts you did not replace is not extended by that.

I hope that helped out a bit. Have a great time!